# How to import Excelsheets in Symfony doctrine entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, import-from-excel

I want to import an ExcelSheet to my DB using Symfony/Doctrine (imported ddeboer data-import bundle)

What is best practice to import the data and first check if the data is already imported?

I was thinking of two possibilities:

1)

```
$numarray = $repo->findAllAccounts();
  $import = true;
  foreach ($reader as $readerobjectkey => $readervalue) {
    foreach ($numarray as $numkey){
      if (($numkey->getNum() == $readervalue['number'])){
        $import = false;
      }
    }

    if($import){

      $doctrineWriter     ->disableTruncate()
      ->prepare()
      ->writeItem(
       array(
         'num' => $readervalue['number'],
         'name'  => $readervalue['name'],
         'company' => $companyid
         )
       )
      ->finish();
```

2)

```
 foreach ($reader as $row =>$value ) {

    // check if already imported 
    $check = $this->checkIfExists($repo,'num', $value['number']);

    if ($check){ 
      echo $value['number']." Exists <br>";
    }else{echo $value['number']." new Imported <br>";


    $doctrineWriter     ->disableTruncate()
    ->prepare()
    ->writeItem(
     array(
       'num' => $value['number'],
       'name'  => $value['name'],
       'company' => $companyid
       )
     )
    ->finish();




 public function checkIfExists($repo, $field, $value){

$check = $repo->findOneBy(array($field => $value));
return $check;
```

Problem is with big exceldatasheets (3000 rows +) with both solutions i get a timeout....

> Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

in general: for performance issues: is it prefered to generate 1000 queries to check if value exists (findOneBy) or to use two foreach loops to compare values? 
Any help would be awesome!

Thx in advance...

Comment: For big imports, drop down to sql and prepared queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the filemtime of the file : http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

I'm not sure if it would work properly but it worth a shot to try it and see if the modified date works as expected.

Otherwise you should think of another way that checking the data like this, it would take lot of resources to do so. maybe adding some metadata to the excel file :

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/phpexcel_library/1.7.4/manual.html#_Toc237519906

Any other way than looping or querying database for large data is better.